# updating specific model keys depending on argument

Tags: javascript, model, sequelize.js

So I'm trying to change a specific key in a model on my database given a specific argument in a function. I can of course do it as repeating if statements, but it's of course not very lucrative or sustainable. Given that in my actual application the `keyX` goes all the way up to 9, I'm not very enticed to solve this problem like this. The example below is of course a simpler enactment of my problem.

```
//model.js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../database/connection');

const model = db.define('exampleModel', {
   id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
   key1: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
   key2: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
   key3: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
   //keyN...
   someotherKey: { type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSON) }
});

module.exports = model
```

```
//insertions.js

const { model } = require('../models/model')

async function insert(argument) {
   if(argument === 1) { model.update({ key1: 'something' }) }
   if(argument === 2) { model.update({ key2: 'something else' }) }
   if(argument === 3) { model.update({ key3: 'something else entirely' }) }
}

insert(2); //desired outcome here is the function only updating the text of key2
```

Essentially I want to change only a specific key depending on what my given argument for the function is. A fix i tried initially was:

```
const desiredKey = `key{argument}`

model.update({ [desiredKey]: "completely new text" })
```

But proved to not do much for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to prepend `argument` by `$`:

```js
const fieldName = `key${argument}`;
await model.update({ [fieldName]: "completely new text" })
```